# OPA: replacement of the topbar

Tags: opa

I've seen that the Bootstrap topbar have been moved to deprecated.

What would be the alternative ? Use the WAppFrame and the set_top_bar method ?

Or use the methods provided by the Navigation module ? But there is no topbar in this module.

What would you advise ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The deprecated version is for Bootstrap <= 1.4.0.

If you use the new CSS, you should use this module instead : http://doc.opalang.org/module/stdlib.widgets.bootstrap/WBootstrap

The equivalent of `Navigation.topbar` is `Navigation.navbar`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for information, this is the code I used to get the same behaviour has topbar :

```
nav = WB.Navigation.nav([{active:<>Home</>, onclick:ignore, href:some("/")}, {inactive:<>LoginLess</>, onclick:ignore, href:some("/boubou")}, {inactive:<>Sign up</>, onclick:ignore, href:some("user/new")}], false)
navBar = WB.Navigation.brand(<>Brand New</>, none, ignore) <+> nav
WB.Navigation.navbar(nav)
```